# Servlet response buffer not flushing without newlines

Tags: java, servlets, buffer, response

My example servlet prints out some data, flushes the buffer, sleeps for 5 seconds, then prints out more data and finishes.

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException
{

  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
  writer.println("Before sleep<br/>");
  writer.print("After newline<br/>");
  writer.flush();
  response.flushBuffer();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
  writer.print("After sleep<br/>");
}
```

I expect the response body leading up to the flush

```
Before sleep<br/>
After newline<br/>
```

to be printed immediately, and 5 seconds later, the last piece.

`Before sleep<br/>`
`After newline<br/>After sleep<br/>`

### But no

When I query this servlet with `curl -v`, the only immediate output is the headers and the response body leading up to (and including) the newline

```
Before sleep<br />
```

with the rest printed after 5 seconds.

`Before sleep<br/>`
`After newline<br/>After sleep<br/>`

### Why?

It looks like the web container is line-buffering the response data. But that means the servlet can only flush response data before a newline, which seems to violate the specification.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

(I am using WildFly 8.2 with Java EE 7 / Servlets 3.1.)

Comment: Just to check, are you certain this isn't behaviour from `curl`? It might be worth looking at the raw traffic with Wireshark so you can see when the actual packets are sent. It may well be nothing, but it's just a thought...

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, you've hit the nail on the head! Just checked, and the client *is* receiving the first piece of the response (leading up to where I call `flush()`) in a single chunk. `curl` was simply not displaying the part after the newline until after the second piece came in 5 seconds later. Must be an artifact of how `curl` decodes the HTTP chunked transfer encoding. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @JonSkeet suggested I look at the actual traffic, I've determined the line-buffering came from `curl`. The raw HTTP response from the servlet returned this immediately

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

26
Before sleep<br />
After newline<br />
```

and after 5 seconds finished it off with

```
11
After sleep<br />
0
```

So maybe `curl` was waiting to show the `After newline<br />` bit as it was reconstructing the response body from the chunked transfer encoding.

Anyways, problem solved. Thank you!

#### (edit)

Note to self: Use this `curl` syntax which does *not* decode chunks

```
curl -i --raw
```

Now I get the output exactly as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The *`PrintWriter`* is buffering the response. You have to call `flush()`, or send a newline.

Comment: OP claims that `After newline<br/>` is *not* printed early.

Comment: Also, I do call `writer.flush()` right before `response.flushBuffer()`.